# Show a rendered image of a UIelement(Visual) in an Image control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, imagesource

I'm developing an application and I would like to implement a feature similar to Microsoft Power Point's paging system where there is a smaller image of the sheets you are working on on the side.

I have the following function which renders an image of the Grid in which the user has to work.

```
private void CreateImageOfPage()
    {
        int width = (int)this.WorkSheetViewModelList.Last().RootGrid.Width;
        int height = (int)this.WorkSheetViewModelList.Last().RootGrid.Height;
        RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        renderTargetBitmap.Render(this.WorkSheetViewModelList.Last().RootGrid);
        PngBitmapEncoder pngImage = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        pngImage.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));

        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));
        Guid photoID = System.Guid.NewGuid();

        String photolocation = "Temp/"+photoID.ToString() + ".png";
        using (var filestream = new FileStream(photolocation, FileMode.Create))
            encoder.Save(filestream);
        Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath(photoID.ToString() + ".png"));
    }
```

My question is, how to get, set or format the path of the saved image to be set as Source of an Image in a XAML? In its current form the path looks like this : "D:\Project\bin\Debug\7fd77420-f62e-44e7-b206-b5ce19f01a9e.png", and it says it could not get the file at this location(for now I just copied the output in, but it will be bound, as it should be).

If the path I've taken is not elegant, is there any other way to do it better, or without saving the image to the disk at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do any image encoding.

Assuming that there is an Image element named `image`, you could directly assign the RenderTargetBitmap to its Source property like this:

```
image.Source = renderTargetBitmap;
```

---

You may change your method to this:

```
private ImageSource CreateImageOfPage()
{
    var rootGrid = WorkSheetViewModelList.Last().RootGrid;
    var width = (int)rootGrid.ActualWidth;
    var height = (int)rootGrid.ActualHeight;
    var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    renderTargetBitmap.Render(rootGrid);
    return renderTargetBitmap;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
image.Source = CreateImageOfPage();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried to put the pieces together and it seems like the images created does not appear. I have the following in the XAML file:
<Image Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Source, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="60" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Visible">

I've assigned the returned value to a property called Source (public ImageSource Source).

Comment: You've bound the Image's Source property to a Source property in your view model (where Mode=TwoWay makes no sense). Does the view model property notify about value changes, e.g. by firing the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Comment: Yes, it does. Here it is:
private ImageSource _source;
        public ImageSource Source
        {
            get { return this._source; }
            set
            {
                this._source = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

The RaisePropertyChanged method is part of a class which implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

For other properties it works well.

Comment: That should work. Try to use ActualWidth and ActualHeight of the RootGrid instead of Width and Height, as shown in the edited answer.

Comment: I've changed it and still nothing, it doesn't appear.

Comment: Does it work if you assign any other image to the Source property, e.g. one created from an existing image file path, e.g. `Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filePath));`?

Comment: That's certainly out of the scope of your initial question, but you may have forgotton to assign the Window's DataContext to your view model instance, so that the Binding has no source object.

Comment: You were right. I've forgotten to set the data context. Yet, by setting it, now it displays an image that is on the hard drive, but it doesn't do anything when it's bound.

Comment: What does that mean? If you load a BitmapImage from file and assign that to the *view model* Source property it works? But not with the ImageSource returned from your method?