# How can I display real time view in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to get real time view and my code is working in windows form but in wpf there is image instead of picturebox.Image. I get an error when I try to make equalization.

Here is the error code:

> Can not implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'System.MediaControls.Image'

Here is the related part of the code:

```cs
if (btn_GetviewWasClicked)
{
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(width, height);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    BitmapData bmpData = image.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
    Marshal.Copy(buf, 0, ptr, 1200000);
    image.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    img_original.Source = image;//Here is the part where the error exist


    Bitmap image2 = new Bitmap(width, height);
    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    BitmapData bmpData2 = image2.LockBits(rect2, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    IntPtr ptr2 = bmpData2.Scan0;
    Marshal.Copy(bf, 0, ptr2, 1200000);
    image2.UnlockBits(bmpData2);

    img_original = image2;////Here is the part where the error exist
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to do as indicated in this thread?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50142401/show-a-rendered-image-of-a-uielementvisual-in-an-image-control-wpf

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I guess,according to the post you suggested I should add '.Source' to the img_original and my problem should be solved but I tried that before and it did not work whereas it works when I write picturebox1.Image=image2 in Windows Form.Must be a easy way for WPF but I really could not find.@
EldHasp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an extension function, like so

```
if (btn_GetviewWasClicked)
{
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(width, height);
    img_original.Source = image.ToImageSource();
}
```

Where `ToImageSource` is an extension function

```
public static class WpfUtils {
    
    public static BitmapImage ToImageSource(this Bitmap src)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        src.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        var image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        image.StreamSource = ms;
        image.EndInit();
        return image;
    }
    
    // Other Utility functions..
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is not working.Maybe I did not make it worked but I already get the data with Marshal.Copy.I could not understand the difference.@Muhammad Sulaiman

Comment: Try removing the 3 lines before `img_original.Source =` please, and I'd like to know what kind of error you got when you use `ToImageSource` method

Comment: And make sure to use `.Source`, because in your code, you have mentiond two placese where the error occurs, one with `.Source`  and the other without it.

Comment: I asked a lot but I wrote this function above of the code and added this instead of that three lines:'img_original.Source = image.ToImageSource();' but it is not working.Could you write the fixed version of my code.I guess I could not place the code properly.@Muhammad Sulaiman

Comment: I've updated my answer, let me know what error you got if `ToImageSource` doesn't work

Comment: Firstly I am getting error for Format24bppRgb:The error is :'Image.Format24bppRgb does not exist in System.Drawing.Image.'The second one is:' 'Bitmap' does not contain a definition for ToImageSource.@Muhammad Sulaiman

Comment: My man, I did not mention `Format24bppRgb` in my code, do not use it.. secondly, `ToImageSource` is a method that you define, I've put it inside `WpfUtils` class, copy this class from my answer and put it below the class you are writing your code in (note: do not remove `this` keyword, it will make `ToImageSource` as an extension method besides the methods inside `Bitmap` class)

Comment: It worked when I fix the code.Thank you for the answer.@ Muhammad Sulaiman